# My node is stopping - error in threading.py

Tags: ros, python2.7, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have written an navigation algorithm, which takes input from an Imu and Hokuyo Urg laser range scanner and uses those to calculate a velocity and a angle for direction.

However my node stop after just about a second when running it.

I have hokuyo_node and razor_imu_9dof running in different terminalwindows.

I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread /scan (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_pubsub.py", line 183, in robust_connect_subscriber
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 792, in receive_loop
> <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable

I code is quite long with lots of different callback - but here goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion


######## defining global variables ############
ranges = []
angle_min = []
angle_increment = []
wheelVel1 = []
wheelVel2 = []
wheelVel3 = []
wheelVel4 = []
target = []
turn = []
orientation = []
blocked = 0

######## Callback functions ####################

def scan_callback(scan):
    global ranges, angle_min, angle_increment

    rospy.loginfo(scan.ranges)
    rospy.loginfo(scan.angle_increment)
    rospy.loginfo(scan.angle_min)

    ranges = scan.ranges
    angle_min = scan.angle_min
    angle_increment = scan.angle_increment


def imu_turn_callback():
    global target
    #use Imu data to for setting target

def imu_row_callback(Imu):
    global orientation

    rospy.loginfo(Imu.orientation)

    q0 = Imu.orientation.x
    q1 = Imu.orientation.y
    q2 = Imu.orientation.z
    q3 = Imu.orientation.w

    #convertering from quaternion to euler degrees_ http://sunday-lab.blogspot.dk/2008/04/get-pitch-yaw-roll-from-quaternion.html
    #Note not the most trust worty source - but formula is vertified

    #yaw:
    yaw = np.arctan2(2*(q0*q1 + q3*q2), q3*q3 + q0*q0 - q1*q1 - q2*q2)
    orientation = yaw

def imu_init_callback(Imu):
    global target
    rospy.loginfo(Imu.orientation)

    q0 = Imu.orientation.x
    q1 = Imu.orientation.y
    q2 = Imu.orientation.z
    q3 = Imu.orientation.w

    yaw = np.arctan2(2*(q0*q1 + q3*q2), q3*q3 + q0*q0 - q1*q1 - q2*q2)
    target = yaw

def encoder_callback():
    global wheelVel1, wheelVel2, wheelVel3, wheelVel4
    #update global wheelVel



######   Subscriber functions  ########

def init_target():
    rospy.Subscriber("imu", Imu, imu_init_callback)

def laser_listener():
    rospy.Subscriber("scan", LaserScan, scan_callback)

def imu_listener_turn():
    rospy.Subscriber("imu", Imu, imu_turn_callback)

#def encoder_info():
#    rospy.Subscriber()##Tilpas encoder msg!!!!, encoder_callback)

def imu_row_listener():
    rospy.Subscriber("imu", Imu, imu_row_callback)


######## Navigation algoritms #################

def turning(): #turning global algoritm -- use IMU for updating new target for row navigation
    global target
    #do turn
    #use IMU for updating global target


def VPH():
    global ranges, angle_min, angle_increment, wheelVel1, wheelVel2, wheelVel3, wheelVel4, target, orientation, blocked
    #Number of scans in plane (#obstacles)
    noPoints = len(ranges)

    #encoder_info() #updates the global wheelVel variables
    imu_row_listener() #get current robot orientation in order to compute current target Dtarget

    Dtarget = np.array(target) - np.array(orientation) #computes a transformed target from the global set target and the current orientation


    #Compute V_t from wheelVel(1-4)
    r = 0.12 #radius of wheels
    V_t = np.average(wheelVel1 + wheelVel2 + wheelVel3 + wheelVel4)*r  #MIDLERTID V_t REPRÆSENTATION - find på bedre funktion

    ### Robot and navigation parameters ###
    D_max = 4 #Max range of laserscanner
    R = 0.3 #Radius of robot
    D = 0.05 #"safe" distance between robot and obstacle
    V_max = 4.0 #robot topspeed
    W_max = 10 #minimal window for opening
    k1 = 4 #coefficient making the path more target orientated
    k2 = 2 #coefficient making the path more smooth

    angI = np.zeros(noPoints)
    H = np.zeros(noPoints)

    for i in range(0,noPoints):
        angI[i] = angle_min + i * angle_increment
        D[i] = ((V_t^2*np.cos(angI[i])*np.cos(angI[i])) / (2*a)) + R + D_safe
        if ranges[i] >= D[i]:
            H[i] = 1

    count = 0
    W = np.zeros(noPoints)

    for i in range(0,noPoints):
            if H[i] == 1:
                count += 1
            else:
                if count >= W_max:
                    for n in range(i - count, i-1):
                        W[n] = count
                        count = 0
                else:
                    count = 0
    U = []
    for i in range(0, noPoints):
        if H[i] == 1 and W[i] >= W_max:
            U = i

    if not(U):
        blocked = 1
    else:
        for i in U:
            C[i] = k1 *(AngI[i] - Dtarget) + k2*AngI[i]
        steering_angle_entri = np.argmin(C)
        steering_angle = angI[steering_angle_entri]
        V = (1 - (D_max - ranges[angI[steering_angle_entri]])/(D_max-(R+D)))*V_max

        #pub = rospy.Publisher("", , queue_size=5)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('mark_pi_navigation', anonymous=True)
    init_target()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        laser_listener()
        if turn==1:
            turning()
        else:
            VPH()
        if blocked == 1:
            print("blocked")#start "I´m stucked navigation
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221534/my-node-is-stopping---error-in-threading.py/) by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix the problem by adding rospy.sleep(1) in the end of the while not rosy.is_shutdown(): statement

---

Originally posted by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) with karma: 30 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1